# How can I pipe output of ffmpeg to ffplay in java?

Tags: java, ffmpeg

currently i have created a java project that allows me to use ffmpeg to split a live video coming from a webcam and fragment it into many 60 second video clips.
These are the main methods:

```
    @Override
public boolean startRecording(String fileName, Integer clipPrefix, String folderClipName) {
    final String methodName = "startRecording(fileName, folderClipPath)";
    this.startLog(methodName, fileName, folderClipName);
    try {
        File folder = new File(folderClipName + System.getProperty("file.separator") +fileName);
        if( !folder.exists() ) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String fileNameFull = buildFileName(fileName, clipPrefix);
    String[] cmd = buildCommandArray(fileNameFull);
    logger.debug("{} - executing FfmpegStartRecordingCommand with cmd:{}", methodName, Arrays.toString(cmd));
    Process p = new FfmpegStartRecordingCommand().execute(cmd);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return p.isAlive();
}

public String[] buildCommandArray(String fileNameFull) {
    String cmd[] = new String[37];
    cmd[0] = "-f";
    cmd[1] = "dshow";
    cmd[2] = "-rtbufsize";
    cmd[3] = "2000M";
    cmd[4] = "-i";
    cmd[5] = cameraName;
    cmd[6] = "-preset";
    cmd[7] = "slow";
    cmd[8] = "-codec:a";
    cmd[9] = "libfdk_aac";
    cmd[10] = "-b:a";
    cmd[11] = "128k";
    cmd[12] = "-codec:v";
    cmd[13] = "libx264";
    cmd[14] = "-pix_fmt";
    cmd[15] = "yuv420p";
    cmd[16] = "-b:v";
    cmd[17] = "1000k";
    cmd[18] = "-minrate";
    cmd[19] = "500k";
    cmd[20] = "-maxrate";
    cmd[21] = "2000k";
    cmd[22] = "-bufsize";
    cmd[23] = "2000k";
    cmd[24] = "-vf";
    cmd[25] = "scale=854:480";
    cmd[26] = "-f";
    cmd[27] = "segment";
    cmd[28] = "-segment_time";
    cmd[29] = "60";
    cmd[30] = "-reset_timestamps";
    cmd[31] = "1";
    cmd[32] = "-flush_packets";
    cmd[33] = "1";
    cmd[34] = "-loglevel";
    cmd[35] = "quiet";
    cmd[36] = fileNameFull;
    return cmd;
}
```

To these I wish I could use a method that allows me to use ffplay at the same time in order to see what I am acquiring?
On the internet I found the following command

```
ffmpeg -i <video> out.mp4 | ffplay -i video
```

but i don't know how to implement it in java.
Some idea??
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you'll need to create one `Process` for `ffmpeg` and another for `ffplay`. Then you'll need a thread to slurp up the output of the first `Process` and push in into the standard input of the second. You'll probably need some buffering in this thread, to keep up with the video data rate. I suspect this implementation will be non-trivial.